# How to write in ruby test that at least one of three variables is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, variables, if-statement

I have this validation:

```
if self.var_a.blank? || self.var_b.blank? || self.var_c.blank?
  self.errors[:base] << "Error." 
end
```

If are all three variables set up or all three are not set up, everything's ok.
But if there is set up one of those 3 or 2 of 3, I need to display the error.

I am fighting with this issue some time, but cannot effectively write it.

Answer (score 4):

```
if [var_a,var_b,var_c].any?{|m| m.blank?}
  self.errors[:base] << "Error." 
end
```

or

```
self.errors[:base] << "Error." if [var_a,var_b,var_c].any?(&:blank?)
```

Comment: Thank you Arup for your answer. Everytime I sent the form with data, I get this error: `undefined method `m' for #<Item:0x007fccc423bcf0>` -- I am using this code in model. Does it mean that I miss a library?

Comment: `var_a ` is an input in form the same way as the other 2 variables.

Comment: Well, this works in the case that all 3 variables will exist. Which is good. But I also would need to work it in the case that none of variable will be set up: thus, all 3 are `blank` or all 3 are not `blank` - that's valid. If it's set up only 1 or 2 variables, then error - so here's not handled the cases that all 3 variables are blank - which I would need to be a valid case.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing syntax here (dont know ruby).. but logic should be something like this:

```
if [var_a,var_b,var_c].any?{|m| m.blank?} && ![var_a,var_b,var_c].all?{|m| m.blank?}
  self.errors[:base] << "Error." 
end
```